# Running Less.js on C#/Javascript.net/V8

Tags: javascript, c#, v8, javascript.net

I'm trying to run [less.js](http://github.com/cloudhead/less.js) in a C# application. I tried running the default distro using [JavaScript.net](https://github.com/JavascriptNet/Javascript.Net) but I'm getting window is undefined error. I think that is caused due to this not being run in a browser but on a JS engine. Is there any workaround / any pointers to resources that can help?

Comment: IIRC, less.js is the module that allows you to use somewhat different syntax in your stylesheets.  If you don't have a page to style...?

Comment: I'm trying to convert a less file to css programatically. Should have mentioned that above.

Comment: Accept, or comment if the answers is unsatisfactorily

Comment: It looks like less.js (looking at the source) should allow you to pass in an undefined window reference, can you tell us what line the window is undefined is happening on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should probably run [.Less](http://www.dotlesscss.org/) instead. If I understand correctly, you are trying to run less.js on the server through a Javascript interpreter. Why not just skip the interpreter and run LESS conversion using all .NET code? Way less pain and overhead.

Comment: I agree, right now less is at 1.5.0 beta version and dotless is still at 1.3.1, which is really bad because frameworks like bootstrap cannot be added and compiled because they use the new less features and dotless parser fails ...

Comment: dotLess is buggy AND it is really an abandoned project that hasn't been updated in over a year. I'll add a better answer if I get one...

Answer (score 0):

This is more a guess: according to the documentation (I have never worked with Javascript.net) the following is valid:

```
// Initialize the context
JavascriptContext context = new JavascriptContext();

// Setting the externals parameters of the context
context.SetParameter("console", new SystemConsole());
context.SetParameter("message", "Hello World !");
context.SetParameter("number", 1);

// Running the script
context.Run("var i; for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) console.Print(message + ' (' + i + ')'); number += i;");

// Getting a parameter
Console.WriteLine("number: " + context.GetParameter("number"));
```

Maybe you should set the window as a parameter to the context ala this:

```
context.SetParameter("window", new YourWindow());
```

And insure the window your providing have the same attributes/methods/etc. as the standard browser window.

**Addition**
You could try and implement a simple window which just writes to the console whenever some function is called on it. Unless of cause, Javascript.Net gives you a window wrapper (does not seem like it though)

Answer (score 0):

Less.js indicates that it's intended to be run under Node.js. Because it sounds like you're writing a .NET app, why not see if [Node.net](http://github.com/dnewcome/Node.net) will help you?